# Dynamic where clause inside a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

I am stucked at a dynamic where clause inside case statement. Here is a block of my sql.

```
Select EstimatedCharges = CASE 
   WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ResidualOverrideConfiguration
        WHERE FacilityCode = @FacilityCode
        AND DRGCode = DRG.DRG AND COALESCE(IsPayorPlanEstimateEnabled, 1) = 1
        AND ChargeAmount IS NOT NULL
        AND COALESCE(FacilityPlanCode, @PrimaryPlanCode) = @PrimaryPlanCode
        AND COALESCE(PatientType, @PatientType) = @PatientType
        AND COALESCE(FacilityPatientType, @FacilityPatientType) = @FacilityPatientType
        AND COALESCE(ServiceFieldCode, @ServiceFieldCode) = @ServiceFieldCode
    )
    THEN (PICK_SOME_FIELD)
  FROM SOME_TABLE
```

Below is my table ,

[image]

In this table `FacilityPlanCode,ServiceFieldCode,FacilityPatientType,PatientType` are optional field that are in use. `FacilityCode,DRGCode,ChargeAmount and IsPayorPlanEstimateEnabled` are mandatory.

My requirement is that if the optional fields are coming null or blank then it should not be a part of where condition.

For example if `FacilityPlancode= null, PatientType=Null` then the Select query inside the case will act like this,

```
SELECT 1
FROM ResidualOverrideConfiguration
WHERE FacilityCode = @FacilityCode
    AND DRGCode = DRG.DRG
    AND COALESCE(IsPayorPlanEstimateEnabled, 1) = 1
    AND ChargeAmount IS NOT NULL
    AND COALESCE(FacilityPatientType, @FacilityPatientType) = @FacilityPatientType
    AND COALESCE(ServiceFieldCode, @ServiceFieldCode) = @ServiceFieldCode
```

Help me out.

### WHAT I NEED

If optional fields are coming null, then I need a way to completely ignore them, assuming they are not in clause.

Comment: Your query seems OK at first glance (though possibly slow), what problem are you having with it?

Comment: @RBarryYoung actually I had a rule "maximum matching optional columns".  Simply I can say, if optional fields are coming null, then I need a way to completely ignore them.

Comment: But your original query *should* completely ignore them.  It's still not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @RBarryYoung No its not ignoring them completely.. which is the problem

Comment: Then please demonstrate that.  What rows is it returning or not returning that it shouldn't?

Comment: See the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

I think the you should use dynamic Sql to build your query and only add the variables that were actually passed a value.

Something like ......

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @Sql = N'Select EstimatedCharges = CASE 
                   WHEN EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM ResidualOverrideConfiguration
                        WHERE FacilityCode = @FacilityCode
                        AND DRGCode = DRG.DRG AND COALESCE(IsPayorPlanEstimateEnabled, 1) = 1
                        AND ChargeAmount IS NOT NULL '
                + CASE WHEN @PrimaryPlanCode IS NOT NULL THEN 
                         N' AND (COALESCE(FacilityPlanCode, @PrimaryPlanCode) = @PrimaryPlanCode) ' ELSE N' ' END
                + CASE WHEN @PatientType IS NOT NULL THEN 
                         N' AND (COALESCE(PatientType, @PatientType) = @PatientType) '              ELSE N' ' END
                + CASE WHEN @FacilityPatientType IS NOT NULL THEN 
                         N' AND (COALESCE(FacilityPatientType, @FacilityPatientType) = @FacilityPatientType) '
                                                                                                     ELSE N' ' END
                + CASE WHEN @ServiceFieldCode IS NOT NULL THEN 
                         N' AND (COALESCE(ServiceFieldCode, @ServiceFieldCode) = @ServiceFieldCode)' ELSE N' ' END
                +   N' )
                    THEN PICK_SOME_FIELD
                  FROM SOME_TABLE'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@FacilityCode INT, @PrimaryPlanCode INT, ......'
                     ,@FacilityCode
                     ,@PrimaryPlanCode
```

### Problem with Other approach

There is a major issue with this other approach, you write your where clause something like...

```
WHERE ( PrimaryPlanCode = @PrimaryPlanCode  OR @PrimaryPlanCode IS NULL)
```

The Two major issues with this approach

1) you cannot force SQL Server to check evaluate an expression first like if `@PrimaryPlanCode IS NULL`, Sql Server might decide to evaluate first  the expression `PrimaryPlanCode = @PrimaryPlanCode`so you will have where clause being evaluated even if the variable value is null.

2) SQL Server does not do Short-Circuiting, if even if it decides to check the `@PrimaryPlanCode IS NULL` expression first and even if it evaluates to true, SQL Server still may go ahead and evaluating other expression in `OR` clause.

Therefore stick to Dynamic Sql for queries like this. and happy days.

Comment: Ali, actually I want my case to work on table's columns, not on the variables. Here you are implementing case on @PrimaryPlanCode(variable) , which is never null.

Comment: come again? so you dont want a value in column to be evaluated if it has NULL value ? is that what you are after ?

Comment: Indeed. You got my point. And the local variables PrimaryPlanCode, PatientType prefixed with @, will always contain some values. It will never be null. As they are coming from some other tables where they are marked as mandatory. Now I have another table as ConfigurationTable where I need to match those columns. In this ConfigTable some are mandatory and some are optional. The table is attached in question.

Comment: In that case the only thing you can do is to provide your query more efficient indexes, 1st things comes to  my mind is `Filtered Indexes` with `WHERE Column IS NOT NULL`.